# How to remove user control from dock panel

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

```
RoomDiagram rd = new RoomDiagram();
maincDockPanel.Children.Remove(rd);
```

when i wright this nothing happens.
how i can remove child and then add new one? thanks

Comment: You need to find the `RoomDiagram` in the visual tree instead of creating a new one. Does it have a name?

Comment: How i can find it? I even dont know how to give it name. i write RoomDiagram k = new RoomDiagram();
            MessageBox.Show(k.Name.ToString()); this and messagebox was emtpy

Comment: Do you mean the control is not defined in your XAML markup?

Comment: i think no. Im new in wpf. please help to remove it

Comment: If it's not in your markup, where are you adding it? Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to remove then you have to use `dockPanel1.Children.RemoveAt()` because `Children` is `UIElement Collection` you may write a small code to ietrate over the collection and see if it is your required control to remove then remove it similarly `dockPanel1.Children.Add()` to add UIElement same should be the case if you are using `UserControl`

some sample code to Iterate over collection and will show you the name of the controls

```
 foreach (Control x in dockPanel1.Children)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Name);
        }
```